# visibility settings for input data on chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the [Fabric-FAQ](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/Fabric-FAQ.html) on the **Data Privacy and Access Control** section it is noted:

> within a channel you can restrict the input data to chaincode to the set of endorsers only, by using visibility settings. The visibility setting will determine whether input and output chaincode data is included in the submitted transaction, versus just output data.

I can find this in both *1.0.5* documentation and in the *latest* but I cannot find where to configure these *visibility options* . Can you point me to a direction?

Thanks!
Panagiotis